# Custom black colored keyboard for iphone application

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am currently working on an iphone app where I want to change default backgroundcolor of keyboard to black.Can anyone provide me sample example/code for implementing the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've asked 6 questions so far on this site and have yet to accept a *single* answer for any of them. If you genuinely feel like none of the answers you have received on any of your questions are acceptable, explain in a comment below the answers why it probably does not work for you. If some answers DID help you solve your problem, mark the one that most helped by clicking the outline of a checkmnark next to the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `keyboardAppearance` property of the text field to `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert`. This gives a black background.

As of iOS7 you can use `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` as well.